# Why is my Javascript for a slideshow not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used some html css and Javascript to create a slide show. I found this tutorial on Youtube and it works for my use. I searched this question on Stack Overflow and apparently someone used the exact same code. My situation is different from that question so **THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE**. But only the css is executed not the Javascript. Does anyone see any problems with this?

Here is my html and css

```
<img id = "myPhoto" src="img1.JPG" alt= "">
<scipt src = "script.js"> </scipt>

#myPhoto{
  margin: 20px 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Here is my javascript

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("myPhoto");

var imageArray = ["img1.JPG", "img2.JPG"];

var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {
  myPhoto.setAttribute("src" , imageArray [ imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
}

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 2000);

myPhoto.onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalHandle);
}
```

Comment: do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: "Not working" is not a good description. You need to post an example that replicates the issue, see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example.*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the javascript effect is not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, what the problem then?

```js
var myImage = document.getElementById("myPhoto");

var imageArray = ["http://placehold.it/150x150", "http://placehold.it/250x150"];

var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {
  myPhoto.setAttribute("src" , imageArray [ imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
}

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 2000);

myPhoto.onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalHandle);
}
```

```html
<img id = "myPhoto" src="http://placehold.it/250x150" alt= "">
```

Comment: The javascript effect is not showing. The images don't "slide". Is there something with where I put my script? Should it be before the img tag?

Answer (score 0):

Bro you should put your script file in the end then it will work correctly

```
<script>....</script> </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script spelling is wrong.
Make it

```
<script src="script.js"> </script>
```